# CLMM post hoc multiple comparisons including the levels of the response variable

Tags: ordinal, emmeans, posthoc

I am running some clmm models for a response variable with 3 ordinal levels

reluctance   surface
none          tarp
none          blanket
some          tarp
some          tarp
lots          blanket
lots          blanket

fmm1 <- clmm(reluctance~ Surface +(1|ID), data = all2)  ####

emmeans(fmm1b,pairwise~Surface,adjust="tukey")

in the summary and in the emmeans, I only get the comparison of the blanket against the tarp but it never includes the comparison in between the levels of my variable response.

it provides me with values informing me if what's happening within each surface differs depending on the surface. I get a p-value telling me that blanket differs from tarp, but that is not what I am interested in.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sag7s.png)

But I want to compare the same levels in each surfaces like presented here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU3ia.png)

I want to get a p-value telling me the "none" reluctance does not differ depending on the surface, same for the other levels.

I know I can get those results if I change my model and put the reluctance as a dependant variable and the surface as the response variable.
fmm1 <- clmm(Surface~ reluctance +(1|ID), data = all2)
But I can't do it, because I want to continue investigating the reluctance with other variables, I just need to prove that the reluctances levels do not differ from a surface to another so I can take out the surface for the rest of my investigation. (My dataset is quite small, I have to avoid over parametrization of the models and run different ones)

Is there a way to get those comparisons using my initial model?

Answer (score 0):

See `vignette("models", "emmeans")`. The default is latent mode, but you need `mode = "prob")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but changing the mode does not change the comparisons I get in the emmeans summary.  It still does not include the levels of the variable response in it.

Comment: Look also at `vignette("sophisticated")` at the section on ordinal models. The examples there will show you what you should expect.

Comment: Thank you !  emmeans(fmm1, ~ reluctance | Surface, mode = "prob") I managed to have something close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Update:  with emmeans(fmm1,pairwise ~ Surface | reluctance2, mode = "prob")I managed to get exactly what I am looking for !